# Saving image._id in react

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

My problem is that I'm fetching images from the backend and let's say i place it in array img
what i did is generate n images in react where n is equal to img.length
lik so

```
img.map((im)=>{
<div>
<img src=im.imagesData />
</div>
}
```

My problem when i try  to add on click which will open a page for this image i want to target which im._id it is
So where i should save my id in the react component so that when I click on it the page it will open its gonna contain this particular image

Comment: You should create a component to display the image, the component could contain a prop that holds onto its Id. If you are unsure how to do this I highly recommend following along with the react practical tutorial https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: Exactly prop but my question in that component file where i should place this prop id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either put in a link, or a callback, like this.

Link:

```
img.map((im)=>(
  <a href={im.id}>
    <img src={im.imagesData} />
  </a>
))
```

Or through a callback:

```
const myImageClick = (id) => { ... }

img.map((im) => (
  <div onClick={(im.id) => myImageClick(im.id)}>
    <img src={im.imagesData} />
  </div>
))
```

Comment: Thankk youu exactly what i want